# Definition of compact support

Tags: analysis

According to http://mathworld.wolfram.com/CompactSupport.html ,

1. A function has compact support if it is zero outside of a compact set.
2. Alternatively, one can say that a function has compact support if its support is a compact set.

My question is, which is the common definition of compact support, $1$ or $2$?

Answer (score 7):

I would say that the former is slightly more simple to parse, in that for the latter, one must recall that the support of a function is the closure of the set of points where the function is non zero when the function is acting on a topological space, rather than just the set of points. The first is also slightly more common in my experience.

Comment: Yeah, I agree. Thanks. So the phrase 'compact support' does not mean the support is compact. That was really confusing to me.

Comment: Yes it *does* mean the support is compact. Please recall the definition of support: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Support_%28mathematics%29#Closed_support .

Both of your definitions are equivalent.